# How to control access to each directory using "ssh + svn"

Tags: svn, ssh

Cannot control access for each directory using "ssh + svn".

Is there no way other than separating repositories?

Even if the following settings are made, “othrt_ssh_user” can access the directory “/ trunk” of the repository “repos” (svn update and commit).

svnserve.conf

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
authz-db = authz
```

authz

```
[/]
* = rw

[repos:/trunk]
some_ssh_user = rw
othrt_ssh_user =
```

---

It turns out that the "repository" is actually a single repository.
The following settings worked fine.

```
[/]
* = rw

[/trunk]
some_ssh_user = rw
othrt_ssh_user =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is perfectly valid and *have to work* (if it's relevant to real state of server)

Just check

1. Repo(s) are really served by `svn+ssh://`, not plain ssh:// ([examine](https://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html) `command`of svn-users)
2. Repo (single repo) in question have name "repos" and section `[repos:/trunk]` is applicable (`svn ls svn+ssh://URL-OF-ROOT` must to show you common base dir of your *repos* or root of single "repos" repository)

Comment: Thank you, I ’ll try it tonight. (Japan time)

Comment: "repos" is actually a single repository.“[/trunk]” worked without problems.Thank you for the resolution.